# Is it possible to display the README.md content before the directory index on GitHub?

Tags: github

When GitHub displays the content of a directory, it first shows an index of the files in the directory and then, if available, the content of an optional `README.md` file. This of course means that one has to scroll down in the README.md file until he or she sees the README.md's content. I find this a bit annoying as I'd rather see the README.md first.

So, is there a way to change GitHub's default behaviour so that the README.md is shown atop of the directory listing?

Answer (score 1):

This will do it.

```
$('#readme').insertBefore('.file-navigation');
```

If you're using Chrome, you could create a button or extension that does that automatically when loading GitHub.

Comment: If I put this line into the `README.md` file, it will be displayed verbatim (as I'd actually expect).

Comment: No, I don't mean copying the code into the repo.  That will just render it as text on the screen.  I mean to create an extension in Chrome or FF to run that code when it detects you're in a repo.  There are countless tutorials on the web to show you how to create extensions.